# Qt5 C++ Application Crashes for unknown reasons

Tags: c++, crash, qt5

I am really struggling with that strange bug for some time. My application crashes even before widgets are shown (but window itself is shown). Here is my code:

main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTimer>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.setWindowTitle("Snake");
    w.resize(500, 500);
    w.show();
    QTimer* timer = new QTimer();
    while(!w.checkCollision())
    {
        if(timer -> isActive() == false)
        {
            w.play();
            timer -> start(1);
        }
    }
    return a.exec();
}
```

mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QPainter>
#include <QKeyEvent>
#include <QDebug>
#include <snakeclass.h>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    Snake snake;
    void paintEvent(QPaintEvent*);
    void keyEvent(QKeyEvent* keyevent);
    void move();
    bool checkCollision();
    void play();
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QPainter>
#include <QPainterPath>
#include <QKeyEvent>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{

}

void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    // Draw black background.
    painter.drawRect(0, 0, 500, 500);
    painter.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500, Qt::black);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < snake.getLength(); i++)
    {
        // Draw green snake's body.
        painter.setPen(Qt::green);
        painter.setBrush(Qt::green);
        // If i = 0, so if we are drawing snake's head.
        if(i == 0)
        {
            // Draw red head.
            painter.setPen(Qt::red);
            painter.setBrush(Qt::red);
        }
        painter.drawEllipse((snake.getDot(i)).x, (snake.getDot(i)).y, 10, 10);
    }
}

void MainWindow::keyEvent(QKeyEvent* keyevent)
{
    if(keyevent -> key() == Qt::Key_Left)
    {
        if(snake.getDirection() != Snake::Direction::RIGHT)
        {
            snake.setDirection(Snake::Direction::LEFT);
        }
    }
    else if(keyevent -> key() == Qt::Key_Right)
    {
        if(snake.getDirection() != Snake::Direction::LEFT)
        {
            snake.setDirection(Snake::Direction::RIGHT);
        }
    }
    else if(keyevent -> key() == Qt::Key_Up)
    {
        if(snake.getDirection() != Snake::Direction::DOWN)
        {
            snake.setDirection(Snake::Direction::UP);
        }
    }
    else if(keyevent -> key() == Qt::Key_Down)
    {
        if(snake.getDirection() != Snake::Direction::UP)
        {
            snake.setDirection(Snake::Direction::DOWN);
        }
    }
}

void MainWindow::move()
{
    for(unsigned int i = snake.getLength(); i > 0; i--)
    {
        snake.editDot((snake.getDot(i - 1)).x, (snake.getDot(i - 1)).y, i, (snake.getDot(i - 1)).direction);
    }
    if(snake.getDirection() == Snake::Direction::UP)
    {
        if(int(snake.getDot(0).y - 10) < 0)
        {
            snake.editDot((snake.getDot(0)).x, 500, 0, snake.getDirection());
        }
        else
        {
            snake.editDot((snake.getDot(0)).x, (snake.getDot(0)).y - 10, 0, snake.getDirection());
        }
    }
    else if(snake.getDirection() == Snake::Direction::DOWN)
    {
        if(((snake.getDot(0)).y + 10) > 490)
        {
            snake.editDot((snake.getDot(0)).x, 0, 0, snake.getDirection());
        }
        else
        {
            snake.editDot((snake.getDot(0)).x, (snake.getDot(0)).y + 10, 0, snake.getDirection());
        }
    }
    else if(snake.getDirection() == Snake::Direction::RIGHT)
    {
        if(((snake.getDot(0)).x + 10) > 490)
        {
            snake.editDot(0, (snake.getDot(0)).y, 0, snake.getDirection());
        }
        else
        {
            snake.editDot((snake.getDot(0)).x + 10, (snake.getDot(0)).y, 0, snake.getDirection());
        }
    }
    else if(snake.getDirection() == Snake::Direction::LEFT)
    {
        if((int((snake.getDot(0)).x) - 10) < 0)
        {
            snake.editDot(500, (snake.getDot(0)).y, 0, snake.getDirection());
        }
        else
        {
            snake.editDot((snake.getDot(0)).x - 10, (snake.getDot(0)).y, 0, snake.getDirection());
        }
    }
}

bool MainWindow::checkCollision()
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < snake.getLength(); i++)
    {
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < snake.getLength(); j++)
        {
            if((i != j) && ((snake.getDot(i)).x == (snake.getDot(j)).x) && ((snake.getDot(i)).y == (snake.getDot(j)).y))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

void MainWindow::play()
{
    //move();
    update();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

snakeclass.h

```
    #ifndef SNAKECLASS
    #define SNAKECLASS

    #include <vector>

    class Snake
    {
        public:

            enum class Direction
            {
                LEFT,
                RIGHT,
                UP,
                DOWN
            };

            // Dot is a part of the snake.
            struct dot
            {
                unsigned int x;
                unsigned int y;
                // Number of the dot (head is 0).
                unsigned int dotNumber;
                // Direction of the particular dot.
                Direction direction;
            };

            unsigned int getLength();
            unsigned int getScore();
            unsigned int getSpeed();
            Direction getDirection();
            dot getDot(unsigned int dotNumber);

            void setLength(unsigned int length);
            void setScore(unsigned int score);
            void setSpeed(unsigned int speed);
            void setDirection(Direction direction);
            // Returns new dot's dotNumber.
            unsigned int newDot();
            void editDot(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int dotNumber, Direction direction);

        private:

            unsigned int length = 3;
            unsigned int score = 0;
            unsigned int speed = 1;
            Direction direction = Direction::RIGHT;
            std::vector <dot> dots = {dot {250, 250, 0, Direction::RIGHT},
                                      dot {240, 250, 1, Direction::RIGHT},
                                      dot {230, 250, 2, Direction::RIGHT}};
    };

    #endif // SNAKECLASS
```

snakeclass.cpp

```
#include "snakeclass.h"

unsigned int Snake::getLength()
{
    return length;
}

unsigned int Snake::getScore()
{
    return score;
}

unsigned int Snake::getSpeed()
{
    return speed;
}

Snake::Direction Snake::getDirection()
{
    return direction;
}

Snake::dot Snake::getDot(unsigned int dotNumber)
{
    return dots.at(dotNumber);
}

void Snake::setLength(unsigned int length)
{
    this -> length = length;
}

void Snake::setScore(unsigned int score)
{
    this -> score = score;
}

void Snake::setSpeed(unsigned int speed)
{
    this -> speed = speed;
}

void Snake::setDirection(Snake::Direction direction)
{
    this -> direction = direction;
}

unsigned int Snake::newDot()
{
    dot newDot;
    newDot.dotNumber = dots.size();
    dots.push_back(newDot);
    length ++;
    return newDot.dotNumber;
}

void Snake::editDot(unsigned int x, unsigned int y, unsigned int dotNumber, Snake::Direction direction)
{
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < dots.size(); i++)
    {
        if((dots.at(i)).dotNumber == dotNumber)
        {
            dots.at(i).x = x;
            dots.at(i).y = y;
            dots.at(i).direction = direction;
        }
    }
}
```

I am new to Qt5 and this is my first project involving painter and keyboard events. Could you help me to figure out what the problem in the code above is? Thank you for all the answers!

Comment: Do you have any message? Try to launch your program from the command line. You might see some. Also, if you are on a unix platform (linux,OSX) you can try to run it in [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/).

Comment: Are you missing a `setupUi(this)` call??

Comment: Where's the stack trace?

Comment: I deleted it on purpose.

Comment: Whats stack trace?

Comment: litelite - i dont have an executable file so i cant lauch it from cmd as far as i know

Comment: If you can run it you have an executable.

Comment: @FilipMirosław 1) What do you mean you don't have executable file? How, then, are you running your application in the first place? 2) Did you try to run your application with a debugger attached, so you could, at least see where your application is crashing, and obtain said stack trace (call stack at the point of crash).

Comment: 1) you are right! silly me! xD i just could not find it because i was looking in the wrong directory!

Comment: 2) when i run it wih debugger application doesnt crash but window is transparent(?!).

Comment: 2) therefore i am not getting any messages from debugger

Comment: Could you please reduce your code to a [mcve]? It will help people figure out where your problem is.

Comment: Is `void MainWindow::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)` even legal for a function definition? What about putting console output lines as "checkpoints" to narrow down the section where it's crashing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My application crashes even before widgets are shown (but window itself is shown).

It doesn't crash. In `main.cpp` there is an infinite loop in which some results are expected, namely `!w.checkCollision()`, but since there is no event loop running in `main.cpp` nothing happens and the programs hangs there waiting in vain.

As an answer to your question, in order to see the widgets add `QApplication::processEvents();` in the following way:

```
while(!w.checkCollision())
{
    QApplication::processEvents();

    if(timer -> isActive() == false)
    {
        w.play();
        timer -> start(1);
    }
}
```

However, with this approach you will face further problems. So I would strongly advise you to take a look at the examples in the Qt Creator in order to see which is the correct way of using the library as thought by the Qt developers.

Comment: @Filip Mirosław, as an additional piece of advice, you don't need to compare the value of a boolean variable in a conditional statement, i.e. it's better to use `if (!timer->isActive())` instead of `if (timer->isActive() == false)`.

Comment: You are right about this one! I seriously need some professional example. Also, can you recommend some Qt5 books?

Comment: It is still a mystery to me why widgets does not show. w.show() which calls paintevent is called before an infinite loop. Also why is it infinite loop? As far as I know checkCollision() will return true at some point.

Comment: @Filip Mirosław, I must admit that I haven't read a single (printed) book about Qt (shame on me). However, there are tons of freely accessible information on the topic out there. My source of knowledge are the documentation http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html, the examples and tutorials (available also from Qt Creator) http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html, as well as some pretty good Youtube series in English https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6KtOzh0StTc&list=PL2D1942A4688E9D63 and in Spanish https://www.youtube.com/user/duartecorporation/videos. And of course - Stack overflow. :)

Comment: Although I personally prefer classic books I will surely check out this YT channel!! Thank you!

Comment: @Filip Mirosław, You're welcome! As for the issue: `int main()` is not a method of a class which inherits from QObject. So, don't expect it to work the same way as MainWindow does for example. Regarding the loop, I've called it infinite, because it will exit on collision and for a collision to occur there should be a movement with the keys and for a key to be processed the events should be processed and it will not happen, because the events are not processed automatically in the main, so in fact the loop will go on endlessly.

Comment: "Events are not processed automatically in the main" does it mean that keyEvent is not called? If so what can I do about it to be called every time user uses the keyboard?

Comment: @Filip Mirosław, yes, that's exactly what I mean. Actually, you can put a `qDebug() << "paint";` in the `MainWindow::paintEvent` and see the difference with or without `QApplication::processEvents();` in the `while(!w.checkCollision())` loop.

Comment: @Filip Mirosław, I have played a little bit with your code and changed it to some extent. It is available at: https://github.com/scopchanov/SnakeGame Take a look at it and tell me what you think.

Comment: I am horribly sorry for not answering for so long!!! Had a look and I think it's great!

Comment: About the problem: I have put QApplication::processEvents() inside the loop. Application is being displayed but still no movement whatsoever.

Comment: @FilipMirosław, did you check how it is done in my example? Btw, you may use it.

Comment: Thank you all solved with scopchanov's help. Scopchanov thank you again.

Comment: @FilipMirosław, anytime